# Cubemapping in opengl using fixed function pipeline

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, skybox

I am trying to get a skybox effect using cubemapping. The skybox is drawn as a single batch of six GL_QUADS. Each face is then manually textured using glTexCoord3f. 
But for each vertex, a vector has to be specified that points to that corner of the sky box. Here is where I am stuck. How do I specify this vector?

Comment: I´m curious. Why is 2D-mapping of the skybox not sufficient?

Comment: Since my six images are loaded in one texture, I thought there was a need to specify which image to map to which face, I managed to get it correctly mapped to a cube with something like this : Here I am drawing only the positive x face of the 2X2 cube.
 
            glTexCoord3f(1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(2,2,2);
            glTexCoord3f(1,1,-1);
            glVertex3f(2,2,-2);
            glTexCoord3f(1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(2,-2, -2);
            glTexCoord3f(1,-1,1);
            glVertex3f(2, -2, 2);

Comment: Why do you load six images into one texture? Again, just curious. I´m sure you know exactly what you are doing :)

Comment: I could load 6 individual textures, but I just did it this way, so can bind all of them with just one texture id.

Comment: Ok. Could you be more precise about this vector? What is it used for? Is it math or applying the vector in OpenGL that is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't think 3d-texturing will work very well. The simple way would be to use 6 2d-textures and bind different textures for each cube face. If you really want to continue please post the code where you load the 2d-textures into a 3d-texture.